# two sqlite db in an iphone app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, sqlite

Is it possible to create an iphone app which manages two separate sqllite DBs? One for static content that should be refreshed by the update process and a second one with user data that doesn't get overridden by the update?

Comment: Unless you have one of the true rare needs for using SQLite directly, you should probably use Core Data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the attach statement from SQLite to make one database visible to the other:

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html

That way, you only need one connection for accessing both databases. Replacing or updating the static content will then have no effect on the user data.

Answer (score 2):

Yes offcourse it is possible. Make sure the names of both the DBs are not the same.

Comment: so the update process lets me selectively update the app and or either one of the sqllite dbs?

Comment: yes, but you need to handle it programmatically, so that when you want to update db_A, the other doensnt get updated/modified. But why dont you use multiple tables in same DB?

Comment: if I can selectively update some tables then I will do it that way

Comment: Yes, you can selectively update tables too. have happy coding :)